# Triggering Report Distribution in BO 4.0

Tags: business-objects

I have a universe and multiple reports built on top of that universe.
Is it possible to configure that when a certain data subset in universe comes, the certain reports are sent to the end-user (stored on file system in PDF format)?
Basically, the question is - is it possible to create a trigger based on the data that are comming in the universe. This trigger triggers report distribution (not all reports, but only specific ones).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to have this reports in some file system in pdf format. am i right? I f so you can schedule the particular report that needs to be distributed.

Regards
Niki

Comment: yes, but the real question is - is it possible to trigger the distribution event after a data set in a database changes? If yes, how?

Comment: will you be knowing when the data set will change? Is it something that it reloads after some particular time? if so in Scheduling u can set that.